# Why is the article used in "downloading a scammer's files"?

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

Is there a rule about such cases? I just can not understand.

> Downloading ***a*** scammer's files.

The name of the video from YouTube.

Comment: **What** don't you understand? Why it's not *the*? Why an article is needed at all? Does your native language use articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because scammer's is  possessive singular.

> Using Indefinite Article: a & an

Rule 1:

A common noun in the singular number always requires an article before it. But a plural common noun does not require an article always. A plural common noun can have the article ‘the’ if we want to particularise that noun.

[Source](https://www.learngrammar.net/english-grammar/rules-of-using-articles)

If the sentence were "Downloading scammers' files", you would not use the article because scammers' is possessive plural.

Consider this example:

"Buying food for a dog."  You use the article because dog is singular.

"Buying food for dogs." You don't use an article because dogs is plural.

To be more exact:

"Buying a dog's food." You use the article because dog is possessive singular, meaning "Buying food for a dog."

"Buying dogs' food." You don't use the article because dogs' is possessive plural, meaning buying food for many dogs (or just more than one dog).

Comment: Does the word "files" play any role?

Comment: No, because the article is referring to the singular scammer not to the files.  Like this:  "Downloading [a scammer's] files."  is singular, using the article.  "Downloading [scammers'] files"  is plural, so it doesn't use the article.